# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}e^{-st}\;dt$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

This is laplace transform of $\dfrac{1-e^{-t}}{t}$ and the integral exists according to [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?s=48&_=1416113858777&i=integrate%20((1-e%5E-t)%2Ft)(e%5E(-st))%20from%200%20to%20infinity&fp=1&incTime=true)

Do i get any help/hints about how to work this ? I have been trying integration by parts with different combinations for u and dv but none of them are working. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write

$$I(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t} e^{-st}\,dt$$

for $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$. Compute $I'(s)$ (by differentiating under the integral sign), and from that obtain $I(s)$ by noting that $\lim\limits_{\operatorname{Re} s \to +\infty} I(s) = 0$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: (+1) In the last step, we get $$I(s)=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much :) I am trying this on my notes

Comment: I am getting $$I'(s) =  -\dfrac{1}{s+1}$$  integrating both sides gives $$I(s) = \ln\left(\dfrac{1}{s+1}\right)$$

Comment: That's not correct as you probably know. You should get $\frac{1}{s+1} - \frac{1}{s}$. What integral did you get by differentiating under the integral sign?

Comment: yeah right after differentiating i have $$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} -s(1-e^{-t})e^{-st} \; dt$$

Comment: here is the complete work $$\begin{align}   I(s) &= \int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{1-e^{-t}}{t}e^{-st}  \; dt\\~\\
I'(s)&= \int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial s}\dfrac{1-e^{-t}}{t}e^{-st} \; dt \\~\\
&= \int\limits_0^{\infty} -s(1-e^{-t})e^{-st} \; dt \\~\\
&= s\int\limits_0^{\infty} -e^{-st} +e^{-t(s+1)} \; dt \\~\\
& = s\left[\dfrac{e^{-st}}{s} - \dfrac{e^{-t(s+1)}}{s+1}\right]_{t=0}^{t=\infty} \\~\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{s+1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: You don't get a factor of $s$ down by differentiating. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} e^{-st} = -t\cdot e^{-st}.$$ So it's $$I'(s) = \int_0^\infty (e^{-t}-1)\cdot e^{-st}\,dt.$$

Comment: Oh my bad yes got it! thanks again!! this is really a cool method xD

Answer (score 13):

Use the fact that

$$\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t} = \int_0^1 du \, e^{-t u}$$

So the integral in question is

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, \int_0^1 du \, e^{-t (u+s)} $$

Because all integrals here converge absolutely, we may switch the order of integration and get

$$\int_0^1 du \, \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-t (u+s)}  = \int_0^1 \frac{du}{u+s} = \log{\left ( 1+\frac1{s} \right )}$$

Answer (score 8):

A last way similar to both Ron Gordon and Daniel Fischer is to use an usefull proposition related to the laplace transform.

> $$\mathcal{L}\left( \frac{f(t)}{t}\right) = \int_s^\infty F(\sigma) \,\mathrm{d}\sigma$$

Given that the integral exists, eg that there exists some $M$ such that $f(t)e^{-t} < M$ for all $t$. 
Here we have $$f(t) = 1-e^{-t} \quad \text{ and } \quad F(t) = \frac1\sigma - \frac1{1+\sigma}$$
Which you should know how to compute by now, or look it up in a standard laplace table. Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}e^{-st}\,\mathrm{d}t
& = \mathcal{L}\left(\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\right) \\
& = \int_s^\infty \mathcal{L}\left( 1-e^{-t}\right) \mathrm{d}\sigma \\
& = \int_s^\infty \frac1\sigma - \frac1{1+\sigma}\mathrm{d}\sigma \\
& = \log (1+s) - \log s
 = \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{s} \right)
\end{align*}$$
And we are done $\square$

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to evaluate the integral is using [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html)
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(at)-f(bt)}{t}\,dt=\bigg[f(0)-f(\infty)\bigg]\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
Taking $f(t)=e^{-t},\, a=s,$ and $b=1+s$ then the integral is simply evaluated to
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+s}{s}\right)$$
which matches up other's answers.

Comment: This is the approach I would have taken.   +1

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \expo{-t} \over t}\,\expo{-st}\,\dd t}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\expo{-st} - \expo{-\pars{s + 1}t}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-tx}\,\dd x\,\dd t}^{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{1 \over t}}}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{-\pars{s + x}t} - \expo{-\pars{s + 1 + x}t}}
\,\dd t\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over x + s} - {1 \over x + s + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\left.\ln\pars{x + s \over x + s + 1}
\right\vert_{\, x\ =\ 0}^{\, x\ \to\ \infty}
=-\ln\pars{s \over s + 1}=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over s}}}
\end{align}

> Another way to evaluate the integral is:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \expo{-t} \over t}\,\expo{-st}\,\dd t}
> =s\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-st}\,\dd t
> -\pars{s + 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-\pars{s + 1}t}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t \over s}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
> -\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t \over s + 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
> =\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}\
> \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}_{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{1}}}
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over s}}}
> \end{align}